# Corona sdk app - can it accept a file from outside the app?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I have an app that reads some CSV data from a file in the DocumentsDirectory but I would like to be able to read similar data into the app via an email attachment or by feeding it to the app on start up.  I know I can use iCloud, Box or other sharing schemes but I'd like to select the attachment in an email and open the attachment with my app. I'm not sure my intended users would have iCloud or such access points.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reason, this may not be possible. Your file should be in Resources or Documents directory.
But, you may be able to update data from csv by loading it from a web server. The user may click on a "Update button" to get the new content.